# Multiple CSS & jQuery-based dropdown menus remain open after clicking on another one

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, menu

I'm setting up multiple jQuery based dropdown menus on one page, based on the following tutorial: http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/07/28/reinventing-drop-down-with-css-jquery.aspx.

I've modified the code on several places now and I've come up with the following solution: http://jsfiddle.net/NcNHf/2/.

It's working pretty well, but I'm looking for a way to **close the other dropdown menus** which are still open when I'm clicking on another one.

So how can I make sure only **one** dropdown menu can be activated on the page at all times?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all dropdowns and filter out current, then hide them all.

```
$(".dropdown > dt a").click(function (e) {
    var $ul = $(this).parent().next().find('> ul').toggle();
    $('.dropdown ul').not($ul).hide();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/NcNHf/3/)